# stop the function by returning something

Tags: ocaml

I am currently trying to make a function that say if a number is a prime number.

Here is what I've done :

```
let is_prime k = 
    for i = 2 to (k-1) do
        if k mod i = 0 then print_string "Not prime"
    done;
    print_string "Prime"
```

As you may have noticed the problem is that when I print Not prime, it doesn't stop the function.

I would like to know if there is a way to stop the function by for example returning `()` right after printing "Not prime".

I know that with pattern matching it does return something and stop the function, but my question is specific to the case where we are not using pattern matching.

Maybe there is a keyword like `return` just as in other programming langages ?

Moreover if I want my function to return `true` or `false` I can't do something like :

```
let is_prime k = 
    for i = 2 to (k-1) do
        if k mod i = 0 then false
    done;
    true
```

It simply doesn't work.

Comment: I think it just answer a part of my question, because I want to stop my loop by returning something, not just stoping it.

Comment: (ty for the link btw)

Comment: Why loops when you have a recursion?

Comment: I've always programmed with imperative langages, I don't quite have the reflex of doing recursion. But it's a good exercise, going to try

Comment: let is_prime k =
    let rec aux acc b = match b with 
      |1 -> print_string "Prime";
      |_ as t -> if acc mod t = 0 then print_string "Not prime" else aux acc (t-1)
    in aux k (k-1)

Comment: Yes something like this, as you can see you don't need exceptions nor any other tricks, and in fact compiled code will be a bit better then the one with exceptions. And generally try to avoid loops in OCaml.

Comment: And this is even nicer I think: `let is_prime k =
  let rec _is_prime k = function
    | i when i = k -> true
    | i when  k mod i = 0 -> false
    | i -> _is_prime k (i + 1) in
  _is_prime k 2`

Comment: You need to understand that Ocaml (and Scheme) has no statements, just *expressions*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I think it answers your question. If you use the exception to break the loop then you can take over and do whatever you want:

```
let is_prime k =
  try
    for i = 2 to (k-1) do
      if k mod i = 0 then raise Exit
    done;
    print_string "Prime"
  with Exit -> print_string "Not prime"
```

You could even return a `boolean`:

```
let is_prime k =
  try
    for i = 2 to (k-1) do
      if k mod i = 0 then raise Exit
    done;
    print_string "Prime";
    true
  with Exit ->
    print_string "Not prime";
    false
```

**Edit following ChrisVine's suggestion**

The following is a more idiomatic way to do what you want without using pattern recognition:

```
let is_prime k =
  let rec is_prime' i k =
    if i < k - 1
    then
      if k mod i = 0
      then print_string "Not prime"
      else is_prime' (i + 1) k
    else
      print_string "Prime";
in
is_prime' 2 k
```

But note that vonaka's solution using pattern recognition is the prefered way.

Comment: Wow, didn't know exceptions were that powerful in OCaml

Comment: This works, but it is not the idiomatic way to do it in ocaml.  In ocaml, for looping on a predicate you would normally use iterative recursion with ocaml's 'let rec' construct and re-loop if an end case has not been encountered.  Please don't encourage beginners trying to learn functional programming to adopt the habits that they have brought in from their imperative programming experience.

Comment: I agree but it seemed that OP was aware of the recursive solution and wanted an answer to this specific case. I also think that learning the syntax of a language and then its idioms is a viable way to go about it.

Comment: @Daiwen: No, the OP was hopelessly confused that a recursive solution requires pattern matching.  Here, it doesn't.  It seems clear to me at least that the OP has not yet discovered iterative recursion and is thinking about the issue in the wrong way.  This is one of the problems of the person asking the question indicating whether it has been solved or not.

Comment: @Daiwen: Your revised version seems fine, although I don't think I would agree that pattern matching with 'when' guards is preferred, because here that would just be a convoluted way of writing an if/else expression (it isn't deconstructing anything).  But that is a matter of taste, and either way is going to emit the same code, and be more efficient than using exceptions.